# How do I prevent a cached page from being served when the user clicks the back button?

Tags: html, caching, browser

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but the solutions posted are not working for me.

I have put the following in the `<head>` tag, to no avail:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

I also saw some mention about the `onunload` attribute and the bfcache in browsers, so I added that to the `<body>` tag, also to no avail.

The response headers from my server contain:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
```

Would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction here - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Back button is pretty much always going to use the cache for most browsers and in fact is usually going to re-use a previously-rendered page still stored in memory. The anti-caching measures only come into play for new requests.

Comment: Thanks - so there's no way to prevent this, other than some JS hack?

Comment: Yeah, anything is going to be a hack, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question.  As it turns out, setting the following response headers (as opposed to `META` tags) worked for me:

```
Cache-Control private, no-store, max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma no-cache
Expires Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

If you're working in Rails like I am, you can do this easily by putting the following in an `ApplicationController` `before_filter` callback:

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "private, no-store, max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: 01 Jan 1990 was not a Friday, it was a Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Using the back button will use the cache as @kindall said.  It really depends on what you don't want cached.

Instead of encouraging users from using the back button can you structure the page navigation so that the user can always get to where they want without having to use a back button?

The stuff you don't want cached can you load it dynamically via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the logged In page with reload() after the session is being terminated in the http() fun, this updates the local cache. Since your session has ended the reload will take you to the login page. Even if you press the browser back button the login page remains, because the local cache is updated.